# AdMob when user clicked button

Tags: android, admob

I want to if user click button show ad and user pass to next Activity

And I try ;

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

      btn_troyaz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();

            }else{
                Intent troyaz = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity1.class);
                startActivity(troyaz);
                finish();
            }
         });

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3179255419692710/2693925385");
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().
                       addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).
                       build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);
```

And I try this one;

```
   btn_troyaz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                Intent troyaz = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity1.class);
                startActivity(troyaz);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
```

but doesn't work When ad loaded it's show ad not pass next Activity other it's pass next Activity but doesn't show ad

Comment: add a listener to your mInterstitialAd, and catch when ad is closed and move to your next activity

Answer (score 0):

First you should show the interstitial and then after user has closed the interstitial you go to the next activity. You could achieve this by adding close listener to the interstitial, something like:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

                // start new activity here

                super.onAdClosed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {                    
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            }
        });
```

Not sure if it is going to be a good user experience though to always show an ad after some button click. Usually interstitials after level completed etc. as recommended in the admob guidelines work best, but that just as a side note